# Where can I find the Stack Overflow for Teams data security reference?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

For [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), I have a question I can't quite find documentation to confirm.

I created a couple of test questions in a test team. After reloading the pages a few times I saw that these questions had been viewed 4 times each. I am unsure where these views are from, but made me think moderators, and there may be team/company external access/review.

Where can I confirm the privacy and access for data posted in Stack Overflow for Teams? Particularly, who would be able to view any data posted in our team?

Comment: Well... You counted as a view as soon as you asked it, and depending on how long the period over which you viewed it a few times was, you were potentially the remaining 3 views as well. Views are not necessarily unique visits (they're IP based with a time limit between re-counts). Re: mods, AFAIK (I'm not in any teams) mods are only mods on SO main they have no access at all to your team unless they are invited to it, staff potentially have access, but even then maybe only database access /shrug

Comment: Yeah, I was mostly thinking the same thing, and the page views do seem to continue to increment. But did want to try to confirm as I would be curious about information under an NDA, ATO, or other security guidelines.

Comment: Section 7 of the teams ToS may cover what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/free

Comment: Yes, this will do nicely. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: On SO proper the Views are counted per unique IP in a 15 minute window. I assume that works similar for Teams.

Comment: Related on main meta: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/241919). Just as rene's stated, it's by design if you reloaded the page after 15 minutes.